# RecyclerView not render cells with 0dp height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I made an app with onboarding flow.
I have a recyclerview in my MainActivity class and I want to update it when onResume hits(Right after the onboarding flow).
So this how the recycler xml looks:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notifyRecycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and this it the cell layout:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/cardDetails"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</...>
```

I swap the data within the adapter with clear and add and everything works great when I change the cell layout view height from 0dp to match parent.
It also works great for the first run from oncreate, but when I try to update from onResume it just not notify the data set changed.
Here's the code of the adapter called from onResume function:

```
public void setNewData(ArrayList<Model> models) {
    this.notifications.clear();
    this.notifications.addAll(models);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

in onCreate:

```
adapter = new NotificationsAdapter(new ArrayList<>(), this);
notifyRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in onResume,I made boolan var to make it update only when resuming the app:

```
ArrayList<NotificationModel> notificationsList = new ArrayList<>();
    notificationsList.add(...);
    notificationsList.add(...);

    adapter.setNewData(notificationsList);
```

Comment: Can you share the code for both onCreate and onResume ? how did you recognize that onResume not notify the data set changed, did you pass different dataset from onResume than onCreate ?

Comment: yes it just a hardcoded dataset and pass it to the setNewData method

Comment: if you are passing the same data set from both the method onCreate and onResume then you can't notice whether data set changed notified or not for the second call. please provide the onCreate and onResume method call along with dataset that you are passing to the setNewData method.

Comment: updated the post

Comment: As per onCreate and onResume code, sounds like there shouldn't be any issue. Tell me what the issue exactly you are getting ? . By looking the code I can see whatever items you set in the list notificationsList, those many items should be getting displayed properly.

Comment: I am bit confused with your statement **It also works great for the first run from oncreate, but when I try to update from onResume it just not notify the data set changed**. What exactly is going wrong ?. It's understood your adapter will notify data set changed only once i.e from onResume.

Comment: I know, as I said before everything works grear when the cell layout uses a real size or match parent for the view dimension,but when I try to use 0dp for the "cardDetails" dimension , the recycler shows nothing althought rhe layout inspector shows that the recyclerview has cells.

Comment: Why do you need cards with size 0?, it is obvious cells with size zero won't be visible.

Comment: Do you know how constraints work?

Answer (score 0):

Wierd solution, Solved by changing the parent ViewGroup from ConstraintsLayout to RelativeLayout.